# how to set a set of results in a choice widget in a symfony auto-generated form (linked to a relation)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entities

I would like to know with the following code, how to display in the generated form, a set of Contacts, linked to the Company of this note, instead of all contacts in the DB?

Entity Note :

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main\MainBundle\Entity\NoteType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $noteType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main\MainBundle\Entity\Contact", inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $contact;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main\MainBundle\Entity\Company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main\MainBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;
```

Entity Company :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Main\MainBundle\Entity\Contact", mappedBy="company", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $contacts;
```

Comment: Please note that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: thats to say I did not want to seem to be asking for a piece of code, like many do. All I needed was the good informations in order to find my answer. I finally git the answer itself... tx to So people.                                          Dammit, Stack overflow is as much usefull as it is codified, in a very wrong way to my mind !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like to use QueryBuilder you can set your contacts in the controller:

```
$oForm = $this->createForm(new CompanyForm($contacts));
```

and in the form you can do this:

```
public function __construct($contacts))
{
    $this->vContacts = $contacts;
}
```

then:

```
->add('contacts', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'contacts',
            'choices' => $this->vContacts,
           )
        )
```

Comment: damn, it's so simple, I should have tried something like this before ! Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get particular set of entities in your form field, you can use [query builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities).

In your case (inside your form type class) it could be something like:

```
$builder->add('contacts', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MainMainBundle:Contact',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($company) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.company = :company')
            ->setParameter('company', $company);
    },
));
```

Pay attention to pass `$company` variable.

Comment: I'll use Besbes's answer, I thinck it's simpler to separate the request from the form, but i'll keep yours in mind in case i need to !